# Finding the derivative of a function by limit definition

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

I want to know how to find the derivative of functions of this sort by definition: $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[5]{x}+\sqrt[4]{x^5}}.$

Specifically this one, I've been struggling with. How does one approach these kinds of limits?

$$f'(x)=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\left(\frac{\frac{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt[3]{x+h}}{\sqrt[5]{x+h}+\sqrt[4]{(x+h)^5}}-\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[5]{x}+\sqrt[4]{x^5}}}{h}\right).$$

I've been trying for a while now. It just seems impossible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If anything these kind of limits show you the power of the differentiation rules (sum/product/power rule). What I would probably do, reminiscing those rules, is to imagine I were proving those rules beginning from the differential quotient and proceeding. For example, remembering the sum rule, I know that I'd first split the numerator into two parts : involving $\sqrt[2]{\cdot}$ and $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}$  terms separately. Then I'd remember the division rule : and attempt to push that through. It's not an easy exercise, but with some care we can get the result we need. The only question is : why?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon,   I will say the teacher gave it as a challenging problem for the student.

Comment: For example, with the division rule, $\frac{\frac{f(x+h)}{g(x+h)} - \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}h = \frac{1}{g(x)g(x+h)}\frac{f(x+h)g(x) - g(x+h)f(x)}{h}$, now use a product rule type subtraction-addition with $f(x)g(x)$ on the second fraction to get two differential quotients, I mean, yes, makes sense.

Comment: @00GB Definitely! That would make sense, if the teacher is wanting to test the extremes of "by-principle" calculation of derivatives. But at the moment, I'd prefer it if the user mentioned the source(even if they are doing it themselves). This is also a good exercise in proof organization : creating little lemmata and then combining them together. But I think I need to ask for improvement in this question.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, Yes, ask for improvement the question and write a nice answer wiht more details as you usually do

Comment: @00GB I wonder if I have the patience! After all, I thankfully do not need to practice differentiation from first principles : the OP needs to do it!

Comment: @OscarVernon What will make this question easier for you to solve, is knowledge of how the sum, the power and the quotient rule are derived "from first principles" i.e. using their differential quotients. Are you aware of these proofs? Further, please mention a source for the question, and edit your post to reflect the answer to my question.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon. I see what you're saying. I did think of that (I'm a maths student, so I am familiar with the proof for the quotient rule), but I was hoping for a simpler answer which didn't go through all that trouble.
The source is an exam (not mine,a friend's). She studies architecture and got asked this on an exam (which concluded several hours ago). She was unable to solve the question, so after the exam ended, she asked me how to solve those limits. Given that the exam consisted of 5 questions and the time to solve it was of 1 hour (I believe), I assumed a shorter solution would exist.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon. Also for someone who isn't familiar with these proofs (such as my friend), such a task seems impossible! Unless an ingeniuos shortcut exists. Whouldn't you agree? Thanks for you answer, by the way!

Comment: @OscarVernon I wish there was a simpler answer that didn't go through the trouble. Please pass on my sympathies to your friend if she has to solve one of these in (possibly) 12 minutes. I am happy I never went through it. But here's a short explanation : differentiation itself is a build-up exercise, in the sense that you start with derivatives of easy-to-do functions "by principle" and use rules to build up to larger functions. So "by-principle" simplification of complicated quotients will certainly involve deconvolution to simpler differential quotients : which requires too much algebra!

Comment: That, of course, does not mean that one *cannot* do this by principles : but invariably, the first *way* of thinking about a question like this is to think of simpler cases, and how we created complications from them. So to speak, we work from complicated to simple, and because we know each function in the expression, we kind of know what differential quotients we need to prepare ourselves for. Lastly, you are welcome! If you can add your comment into the question post, it will count as context (and enough of it as well, since you include a source and have mentioned your friend' background).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon You mentioned before something about adding the context, and someone else mentiones something about "improvement". What should I write and how do I do this? Hehe. Thank you, I'm new to the site (at least as a contributor).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon You mentioned before something about adding the context, and someone else mentiones something about "improvement". What should I write and how do I do this? Hehe. Thank you, I'm new to the site (at least as a contributor).

Comment: @OscarVernon Aha, thanks for asking. You see, it's not difficult : you actually did quite a bit of work in the comments. See Oscar, we ask people to say something about their question in addition to mentioning it : that's referred to as "context". Context includes the source of your question , and the background of the person who received the question (which is usually the MSE asker, but in this case it's your friend with an architectural background). You mentioned this in the comments : so that's context. If that comment can be fitted into the question post, then your question will have...

Comment: .... a background, a source, a clear instruction for computation, and a clear problem statement, it becomes a good, "improved" question. If , in addition, you specify "some" part of what you tried (maybe that which felt most promising but didn't work out) then you can mention it as well , if you feel that another user can continue from there. If you do not know MathJax, I can assist you with this as well! I just want to make sure that people like your question : I feel like this is a kind of question that everybody (pursuing mathematics of course!) should do at least once in their life!

Comment: About the question itself : I thought, very briefly, about a change of variable in the limit , about setting $y = x^{15}$ and $(y+k) = (x+h)^{15}$ (Note that $k$ can be explicitly calculated as a function of $x$ and $h$ using the binomial theorem) , allowing for a rewrite of the limits. Perhaps I will attempt this approach  : then try to bring it to a "chain rule" type limit. But at this moment, I'm still struggling with how someone was given this in an actual exam! I'd be given it for homework maybe, but an exam! Ouch.

Answer (score 1):

If
$f'(x)=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\left(\frac{\frac{u(x+h)}{v(x+h)}-\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}}{h}\right)$

then
we can write

$f’(x)=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\left(\frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h.v(x+h)}-\frac{u(x)}{v(x).v(x+h)}.\frac{v(x+h)-v(x)}{h}\right)$

Setting

$u(x)=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}$

and

$v(x)= \sqrt[5]{x}+x.\sqrt[4]{x}$,

we have

$u’(x)=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h}=$
$=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt[3]{x+h}-\sqrt{x}-\sqrt[3]{x}}{h}=$

$=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}.\frac{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}+\displaystyle{ \lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+h}-\sqrt[3]{x}}{h}.\frac{\sqrt[3]{(x+h)^{2}}+\sqrt[3]{(x+h)x}+\sqrt[3]{x^{2}}}{\sqrt[3]{(x+h)^{2}}+\sqrt[3]{(x+h)x}+\sqrt[3]{x^{2}}}=$

$=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{x+h-x}{h. (\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}) }+\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{x+h-x}{h.(\sqrt[3]{(x+h)^{2}}+\sqrt[3]{(x+h)x}+\sqrt[3]{x^{2}})}=$

$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^{2}}}.$

Moreover
we have

$v’(x)=\displaystyle{ \lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{v(x+h)-v(x)}{h}=$,

$=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{\sqrt[5]{(x+h)}+(x+h)\sqrt[4]{x+h}-\sqrt[5]{x}-x\sqrt[4]{x}}{h}=$,

$=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{ \sqrt[5]{(x+h)}-\sqrt[5]{x}} {h}.$

$.\frac{  \sqrt[5]{(x+h)^{4}}+\sqrt[5]{x.(x+h)^{3}}+\sqrt[5]{(x+h)^{2}.x^{2}}+\sqrt[5]{(x+h).x^{3}}+\sqrt[5]{x^{4}} } { \sqrt[5]{(x+h)^{4}}+\sqrt[5]{(x+h)^{3}x}+\sqrt[5]{(x+h)^{2}x^{2}}+\sqrt[5]{(x+h)x^{3}}+\sqrt[5]{x^{4}} }$

$+
\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{(x)(\sqrt[4]{x+h}-\sqrt[4]{x}) }{h}.\frac{\sqrt[4]{(x+h)^{3}}+\sqrt[4]{(x+h)^{2}x}+\sqrt[4]{(x+h)x^{2}}+\sqrt[4]{x^{3}} }{\sqrt[4]{(x+h)^{3}}+\sqrt[4]{(x+h)^{2}x}+\sqrt[4]{(x+h)x^{2}}+\sqrt[4]{x^{3}} }+\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{ h\sqrt[4]{x+h}}{h}=$

$=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{x+h-x}{h.(\sqrt[5]{(x+h)^{4}}+\sqrt[5]{(x+h)^{3}x}+\sqrt[5]{(x+h)^{2}x^{2}}+\sqrt[5]{(x+h)x^{3}}+\sqrt[5]{x^{4}})}+
\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{(x)(x+h-x) }{h.(\sqrt[4]{(x+h)^{3}}+\sqrt[4]{(x+h)^{2}x}+\sqrt[4]{(x+h)x^{2}}+\sqrt[4]{x^{3}}) }+\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{ h\sqrt[4]{x+h}}{h}=$

$=\frac{1}{5\sqrt[5]{x^{4}}}+\frac{x}{4\sqrt[4]{x^{3}}}+\sqrt[4]{x}$

Finally
$f’(x)=\frac{8+18\sqrt[6]{x}-55x\sqrt[20]{x}-45x\sqrt[60]{x^{13}}} {60\sqrt[15]{x^{13}}(1+x\sqrt[20]{x})^{2} }.$

Answer (score -1):

While the quotient rule is certainly valid, I have found that it is easier to stick with the product rule.  I would also remove all of the radical signs.  I would therefore re-write the function as

$$f(x) = \left[\left(x\right)^{(1/2)} + \left(x\right)^{(1/3)}\right]
~\times~ \left[\left(x\right)^{(1/5)} + \left(x\right)^{(4/5)}\right]^{(-1)}. \tag1$$

Then, I would (again) re-write the function as
$$f(x) = A(x) \times \left[B(x)\right]^{(-1)}\tag2 $$

where

$$A(x) = \left[\left(x\right)^{(1/2)} + \left(x\right)^{(1/3)}\right] ~~\text{and}~~
B(x) = \left[\left(x\right)^{(1/5)} + \left(x\right)^{(4/5)}\right]. \tag3 $$

At this point, I would focus on equation (2) above, noting that

$$f'(x) = A(x) ~\left\{(-1)\left[B(x)\right]^{(-2)} B~'(x)\right\} ~+~ \left[B(x)\right]^{(-1)}A'(x). \tag4$$

At this point, it remains to :

- manually compute $A'(x)$ and $B'(x)$.
- use the values for $A(x), B(x), A'(x),$ and $B'(x)$ to *fill-in-the-blanks* for equation (4).

$$ A'(x) = (1/2)~x^{-(1/2)} ~+~
(1/3)~x^{-(2/3)}. \tag5$$

$$ B'(x) = (1/5)~x^{-(4/5)} ~+~
(4/5)~x^{-(1/5)}. \tag6$$

---

So now, it only remains to combine the values from equations (3), (5), and (6), in accordance with equation (4) above.

$$f'(x) = \left[\left(x\right)^{(1/2)} + \left(x\right)^{(1/3)}\right] $$

$$\times ~\left\{(-1)\left[\left(x\right)^{(1/5)} + \left(x\right)^{(4/5)}\right]^{(-2)} 
\left[(1/5)~x^{-(4/5)} ~+~
(4/5)~x^{-(1/5)}\right]\right\}$$

$$ ~+~ \left[\left(x\right)^{(1/5)} + \left(x\right)^{(4/5)}\right]^{(-1)}$$
$$\times \left[(1/2)~x^{-(1/2)} ~+~
(1/3)~x^{-(2/3)}\right]. $$

Comment: I urge you to finish your derivation.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Your comment is both (very) reasonable and controversial.  The OP indicated that this problem was given during an in-class examination.  In such a setting, I would ask two questions: [1] What is the intent of the problem composer? [2] How necessary is it to *look for simplifications in the final computation?  Personally, I think, as another comment has mentioned, that the intent of this problem is to test for knowledge of the product &/or quotient rules, and for knowledge of how to attack the question in an organized manner.  ...see next comment

Comment: @DavidG.Stork In an in-class setting, the possibility of a clerical error, looking for elegant simplifications is simply too great.  That is, the instructor has the right to assume that the  *final computation* will be accurate, but does not have the right to expect that the final computation will implement elegant simplifications.  If I was taking the test, the answer that I posted would be my final computation.  Assuming that the analysis/answer is accurate, if the instructor wants to partially penalize because I did not find the most elegant simplifcation, so be it.

Comment: @user2661923 I'm afraid the intent of the problem isn't to test for knowledge of any rules. That's precisely what originated my question. You see, I asked my friend if she had tried the quotient rule... she told me they hadn't studied it! 
She mentioned all derivatives in her classes were solved via limits (they do know some rules, such as the power rule, but they haven't seen ANY theorems or proofs). Basically, they only know how to solve limits, and that the derivative of $x^{n+1}=(n+1)x^n$, for rational n which they assume as they didn't prove the inverse function theorem...

Comment: @user2661923 This is the reason why I wanted to know whether a simple solution existed with only this knowledge and (of course) which didn't turn out to be equivalent (conceptually, at least) to proving the quotient rule, as that is an abusive question to ask in a 1 hour examination in a career in which nobody proves ANYTHING (she studies arquitechture, not maths or anything of the sort...).

Comment: @OscarVernon I avoided the quotient rule by using the more straight-forward product rule that (in effect) $$\frac{d}{dx} [f(x) \times g(x)] = \left\{ [f(x) \times g'(x)] + [g(x) \times f'(x)] \right\}.$$  I also used the exponent rule that $$\frac{d}{dx} ~x^{(a/b)} = \frac{a}{b} \times x^{(a/b) - 1}.$$  In my opinion, the problem can not be attacked without using the two rules: the product rule and the exponent rule.

Comment: @OscarVernon The point of my (arguably) incomplete answer + subsequent comments, was simply that the only analysis that I considered relevant was **how** to use the product rule and the exponent rule in as organized a manner as possible.  Personally, while you do have the (alternative) **limit** approach: $$\frac{d}{dx} ~f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h},$$  I would never even consider using the limit approach for problem similar to the one that you posted.  In fact, the whole point of the product and exponent rules is to avoid having to use the limit approach.